# How do I set for XTS mode when installing ubuntu with guided setup for encrypted LVM?

Tags: encryption

I read that CBC-ESSIV is used as the default mode for LVM entire disk encryption. I want to use XTS mode instead. How do i select this when installing?

Answer (score 1):

The block cipher used by LVM disk encryption is unfortunately not something can be configured during the Ubuntu installer.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable breaking out a little from the normal installation procedure, this guide will get you encrypted root and swap partition using XTS:

http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/ubuntu-aes-xts-plain64/

LVM is not specifically addressed, though.